# How to suspend a reactive calculation until an action button is triggered?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

In the below **Example Code 1**, a user input table `hottable_1` is generated at the top of the UI window. A results table is generated beneath, `alloc_tbl`, which shows the user input into `hottable_1` in its first row and the product of that user input and 2 in the second row, with response deliberately slow for example purposes using the `calc()` function. If the user inputs into `hottable_1` and then immediately triggers the `addSeries` action button, the tables start bouncing due to slow speed of `calc()`. I'm trying to trigger calculations of `calc()` through the use of the `calculate` action button shown in Example Code 1. If the user inputs into `hottable_1` and then immediately triggers `addSeries`, then a new column should be added with default values of 1 and 2 in the first and second rows respectively (and no bouncing).

In **Example Code 2** below I derive an extremely simple example of triggering calculations through an action button, but I am having trouble implementing that solution into Example Code 1. Any suggestions for how to do this?

Below is an illustration of the 2 examples:

[image]

**Example Code 1:**

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

seriesGenTrm <- data.frame('Series_1' = c(1), row.names = c("Input_1"))

calc <- function(x) {
  x <- max(x, 1)
  Sys.sleep(x)
  result <- x * 2
  result <- data.frame(c(x,result))
  result
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable_1'), br(),
  actionButton("addSeries", "Add series"),
  actionButton("calculate", "Calculate"), 
  tableOutput("alloc_tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  seriesTbl_1 <- reactiveVal(seriesGenTrm)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable_1, {
    seriesTbl_1(hot_to_r(input$hottable_1))
  })
  
  output$hottable_1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(
      data.frame(seriesTbl_1(), check.names = FALSE),
      rowHeaderWidth = 100
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newSeriesCol_1 <- data.frame(c(1))
    names(newSeriesCol_1) <- paste0("Series_", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable_1)) + 1)
    seriesTbl_1(cbind(seriesTbl_1(), newSeriesCol_1))
  })
  
  addCol <- function(allocData, columnName, seriesTbl_1) {
    allocData[[columnName]] <-
      calc(seriesTbl_1()[1, colnames(seriesTbl_1()) == columnName])
    return(allocData)
  }
  
  allocData <- reactive({
    allocDataTmp <- data.frame(Row = 1:2)
    for (colName in colnames(seriesTbl_1())) {
      allocDataTmp <- addCol(allocDataTmp, colName, seriesTbl_1)
    }
    return(allocDataTmp)
  })
  
  output$alloc_tbl <- renderTable({allocData()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Example Code 2:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("input_value", "Enter a number:", value = 1),
  actionButton("calculate", "Calculate"),
  textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  inputValue <- reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$calculate, {inputValue(input$input_value)})

  calc <- reactive({
    if (input$calculate > 0) {
      Sys.sleep(3)
      result <- inputValue() * 2
      return(result)
    } else {
      return(NULL)  
    }
  })
  
  output$result <- renderText({
    result <- calc()
    if (!is.null(result)) {
      return(paste("Result:", result))
    } else {return(NULL)}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wrap the current contents of the reactive in a call to isolate(). And a reference the calculate button outside the call to isolate but inside the reactive. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment, I believe this gives you what you want.  Note that I've made some changes that remove your `if` statments and do the same thing in a more "Shiny-like" manner.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("input_value", "Enter a number:", value = 1),
  actionButton("calculate", "Calculate"),
  textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  calc <- reactive({
    input$calculate
    isolate({
      Sys.sleep(3)
      input$input_value * 2
    })
  })
  
  output$result <- renderText({
    req(calc())
    
    paste("Result:", calc())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I posted another possible solution answer, using the Example Code 1 instead. Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

seriesGenTrm <- data.frame('Series_1' = c(1), row.names = c("Input_1"))

calc <- function(x) {
  x <- max(x, 1)
  Sys.sleep(x)
  result <- x * 2
  result <- data.frame(c(x, result))
  result
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable_1'), br(),
  actionButton("addSeries", "Add series"),
  actionButton("calculate", "Calculate"),
  tableOutput("alloc_tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  seriesTbl_1 <- reactiveVal(seriesGenTrm)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable_1, {
    seriesTbl_1(hot_to_r(input$hottable_1))
  })
  
  output$hottable_1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(
      data.frame(seriesTbl_1(), check.names = FALSE),
      rowHeaderWidth = 100
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newSeriesCol_1 <- data.frame(c(1))
    names(newSeriesCol_1) <- paste0("Series_", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable_1)) + 1)
    seriesTbl_1(cbind(seriesTbl_1(), newSeriesCol_1))
  })
  
  addCol <- function(allocData, columnName, seriesTbl_1) {
    allocData[[columnName]] <-
      calc(seriesTbl_1()[1, colnames(seriesTbl_1()) == columnName])
    return(allocData)
  }
  
  allocData <- reactiveVal(data.frame(Row = 1:2, Input_1 = c(1, 2)))
  
  observeEvent(input$calculate, {
    allocDataTmp <- data.frame(Row = 1:2)
    for (colName in colnames(seriesTbl_1())) {
      allocDataTmp <- addCol(allocDataTmp, colName, seriesTbl_1)
    }
    allocData(allocDataTmp)
  })
  
  output$alloc_tbl <- renderTable({allocData()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```